# rails performance test is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-prof

Simple performance test, I have installed ruby-prof and no other gems
are missing,

rake test:profile returns the following error.

the test is simply.

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'performance_test_help'

# Profiling results for each test method are written to tmp/performance.
class BrowsingTest < ActionController::PerformanceTest

  def test_homepage
    get '/'
  end
  def test_post_show_page
      get '/posts/first-post'
  end
end
```

line 18 in environment.rb is simple..

```
    config.logger = CustomLogger.new(config.log_path,
config.log_level)
```

here is the custom logger http://pastie.org/1224832
Why is it coughing here?

This is REE 1.8.7 on rails 2.3.5

```
** Invoke test:profile (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:profile
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/
rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/performance/
browsing_test.rb"
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/
active_support/dependencies.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized
constant ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger::FileUtils (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/
active_support/buffered_logger.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/username/Apps/app_name/config/environment.rb:18:in `new'
        from /home/username/Apps/app_name/config/environment.rb:18
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:
111:in `run'
        from /home/username/Apps/app_name/config/environment.rb:10
        from ./test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
        from ./test/test_helper.rb:2
        from ./test/performance/browsing_test.rb:1:in `require'
        from ./test/performance/browsing_test.rb:1
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/
rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/
rake_test_loader.rb:5
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/
rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/
rake_test_loader.rb:5
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/
usr/loc...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, turns out I had to run the profile test with an enviornment variable like..

rake test:profile RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should always run tests using the test environment. That is what it's for. The error will be related to your `CustomerLogger` class.